# Why isn't React recognizing the CSS file I've linked in Index.html?

Tags: css, web, app, react

I've built a meme generator using React as an early project to master the basics. I have 6 files in my "mememaker" folder on my desktop, which I created using "create-react-app". They include: index.html, the parent file that will be displayed which links to style.css and index.js. Index.js is simply rendering the App.js component, which in turn has two child components, the header of the page, and the meme-generator itself (which works by putting text onto an image returned from an API). Everything seems to be working okay, except for the fact that none of the styling from "style.css" seems to be applied to the page, so it looks terrible.

The code within the files is fine, because all the functionality is there, but none of the CSS in style.css is being applied at all, so I suspect there's something wrong either with file pathing or the commands I'm using to build the application (which, by the way, is just running "npm start" once in the src folder).

I've been trying to get this to work for days--please help!

Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

In react/js world you should import your css in a javascript file instead. App.css should be added for you and you can make all CSS changes there.

Or you can import the style file you created (like in App.js)

```
import "./style.css";
```

Assuming your style.css file is in the same file as the js file you're importing from

Comment: https://github.com/react-cosmos/create-react-app-example/blob/master/src/App.js